# Does same characteristic polynomial and same rank imply similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Are two matrices with the same characteristic polynomial and the same rank necessarily similar? Where can I find the proof for such a thing?

Comment: No. $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \not\sim \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The converse is true: two similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial and rank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrices

$$I=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$
have the same characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^2$ and are both full rank but they are not similar since the identity matrix $I$ is only similar to itself.